# orthogonal projection of a point $\vec{\text{b}}$ to the subspace wrt A

Tags: linear-algebra

A post on Quroa:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-special-about-the-matrices-AA-T-and-A-TA-Why-do-they-show-up-in-things-like-least-squares-and-SVD-I-would-like-an-intuitive-or-geometric-interpretation-of-why-these-matrices-and-their-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-accomplish-what-they-do#

stated that the orthogonal projection of a point $\vec{\text{b}}$ to the "subspace" defined by $A\vec{\text{x}}=\vec{\text{b}}$ is given by $$A^T(A\vec{\text{x}_0}-\vec{\text{b}})=0$$

I'm not clear how this equation can be useful since $A\vec{\text{x}_0}-\vec{\text{b}}=\vec{\text{0}}$ and  any vector dotted with a zero vector will yield zero. isn't the above equation redundant?

Also, second question, is it correct that, for $\vec{\text{x}_0}$ to exist, $A$ must not be a full rank matrix? if so, how to formally prove that?

Comment: Do you mean the subspace defined by $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$?

Comment: Also, why is $A\vec{\text{x}_0}-\vec{\text{b}}=\vec{\text{0}}$? What assumptions are you making about $\vec{x}_0$ and $\vec b$? Are you assuming that $\vec{b}$ is in the column space of $A$?

Comment: Yeah, I think that definitely will make more sense. by the way, $A\vec{\text{x}_0}-b\vec{\text{b}_0}=\vec{\text{0}}$ because $\vec{\text{x}_0}$ is on V.

Comment: I saw this on Quora:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-special-about-the-matrices-AA-T-and-A-TA-Why-do-they-show-up-in-things-like-least-squares-and-SVD-I-would-like-an-intuitive-or-geometric-interpretation-of-why-these-matrices-and-their-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-accomplish-what-they-do#

Comment: Well usually you project onto the column space of $A$ not its nullspace. So if $A\vec{x_0} = \vec b$ then $\vec b$ is already in the column space and there's nothing to do: the projection is just $\vec b$.

Comment: Right. He was answering a question about the use of $A^T$. so he meant projection can be solve with that equation. Could you infer whether $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ was what he meant?

Comment: I think that he might mean projection of a point other than $\vec{b}$

Answer (score 1):

To my best guess, the author made a typo in his original statement.
According to the purpose of his answer, the coordinate should be given by:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
A\vec{\text{x}}=\vec{\text{b}} \\
A^T(\vec{\text{x}}-\vec{\text{b}})=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Here is my example:

\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3  \\
4 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad \vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}
7  \\
14
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

plugging them  into the equation yields:
\begin{equation*}
\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
-91  \\
63
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

which is verified to be in the column space of A and $\vec{x}-\vec{b}$ is perpendicular to the column space.